# Is there an English word for "awaiting approval"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm developing a web application. Some of the entities on that application require to be "approved" before they are considered "valid" by the system. I need to name the state in which they are "awaiting approval".

Is there a shorter construction to convey the same meaning as "awaiting approval"?

Comment: Is this a message intended for a user to read, or a type name, or something else? If not the former, **Unapproved** might do it for you.

Comment: I disagree: there is a pragmatic difference between "pending approval" and "unapproved": the former means that it *may yet be approved* while the latter *usually* suggests that it has been judged and has not been approved.

Comment: @msanford: I said _might_, being well aware of the differences which I cared not to pollute the comment thread with by elaborating all possible angles, but was still willing to offer an option; the idea was that if the 'states' are in code, then 'judged and declined' would have its own state. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: This is true and I do agree that it may well be appropriate. I was merely offering another angle.

Comment: I'd use "rejected" rather than "unapproved" for something which has been judged and not approved. This argument, however, makes "unapproved" ambiguous at best. I'd maybe use it for a state in the code (where a comment can describe what it means to someone who needs to use it), but probably not on the UI, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could try "pending", as in "pending approval".

> **pending**
>
> 1. Not yet decided or settled; awaiting conclusion or confirmation.
>    <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pending)</sub>

Comment: +1 - Of all the synonyms I've seen on my NOAD, this sounds like the most appropriate.

Answer (score 9):

You don't *await **for*** something, you just *await* it (see green line below).

I don't see anything wrong with awaiting approval in a general sense, though, as suggested above (and in NGrams), **pending** does seem the most appropriate.

[image: "Google NGrams plot of "Pending approval" marginally leading "awaiting approval" with no results for "awaiting for approval" (see comment).]

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use the word "[pending](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pending)".

But you may find [these other synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/pending) more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

"Pending" is a fantastic choice, but my first thought was "submitted" as in "submitted for approval".

Answer (score 2):

If there is a good chance that any given entity will be considered ***invalid*** by the system, I would say that the entity was *pending **classification***, rather than *pending approval*.