# How to say "Pending review" in a shorter way

Tags: single-word-requests

What word can I use to describe that a set of submissions of an assignment are pending review. I want the shorter word.

Right now I say:  '8 pending review'

But that is too long. I would like to use just one word. What could be a shorter way to convey the same meaning?

It is going to be a simple label in a web application, so it doesn't need to be a full phrase.

Comment: Why the downvotes? If you have issues, expose them here as comments so I can address them and write a better question.

Comment: My down vote is because your question is asking for something that almost certainly won't help anybody else.

Comment: @MattЭллен That's a reason that I really disapprove. You can vote for close if something is too localized, but which one fits: "it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet" None of them. I understand the issue behind that question and it isn't worth any downvote (for the reason you gave). It's another thing if the question is good or not from another point of view, but the reason you gave does not really exists.

Comment: @Em1 unfit questions get down votes from me. I've also voted to close.

Comment: Related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23775/18655

Comment: Hard to consolidate the meaning of "pending review" in a shorter phrase.  If space is truly at a premium in your web app, how about an icon or pictography.  Have an icon of a document with a question mark, attention symbol, clock, or similar overlay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing your comment to Hugo's answer that you believe the concept of "review" is essential, it's hard to see how you'll get a phrase that fully expresses the idea and is shorter than "pending review". Yes, if you write just "Pending" you lose the idea of "review". You could write "Review", but then you lose the idea of "pending". I don't know of any single short English word that means "pending review".

The reason we have adjectives and adverbs is because it's impractical to have a different noun or verb to express every possible combination of attributes. Two words is often as concise as it's going to get.

Comment: That is a fair issue. I am inclined to use 'ready to review', since that conveys the action that I want the user to perform and also the state of the task. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If "pending review" is too long, simply say "pending":

> 8 pending

Comment: I want the focus on the Review part, because pending could be confusing. I was considering using 'reviewable'. Does that sound good in english?

Comment: @Nerian You should've add that important point into the question. I don't think that there will be any good solution regarding that condition. Reviewable might be possible, but I'm not sure if it still thave the same connotation and also it is not really shorter.

Answer (score 3):

There are eight submissions still to review, so just say that.

- 8 to review

Answer (score 3):

Since this is prior to review, you could say "unreviewed."

Or if the review will result in acceptance, you could say "unaccepted." If the review will result in approval, you could say "unapproved."

Answer (score 2):

You can use **"awaiting"** or **"in line"**. Eg,

> - 8 awaiting
> - 8 in line